# How can i return the date of max id?

Tags: mysql, max

I want to select the max `id_product` and date that corresponds to this max id.
my problem is that it returns the max id_ product with a different date.

I can't use the max(date) because it will return always the max what i need is the date of this max id.

This my query :

```
 SELECT 
   MAX(id_product),
   `date` 
 FROM `products` 
 WHERE `fk_stat` = '1' and `id_order` = '77185' ;
```

The result:

[image]

But the value that's must return:

```
09/07/2015 for id = 152752
```

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Next time try adding inserts as actual text statemenst, or prepare [a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: @jkavalik i added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a subquery for this. It can be simple and more efficient:

```
SELECT id_product, date  
FROM products
WHERE fk_stat = 1
  AND id_order = 77185 
ORDER BY id_product DESC
LIMIT 1 ;
```

Comment: That was my first approach, she said it didn't work for her. Lol

Comment: @oNare, no, your first query had `MAX(date)` and it did not have `LIMIT`.

Comment: @oNare what u wrote to me it did not work

Comment: @ypercube i want to use the same query for another problem it's works if i specify the id in where with limit 1 i if want to use it for all data it dosen't work.

Comment: @Sarah, I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: @ypercube i post it my question if u can help me.    http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107901/how-can-i-use-the-same-query-for-all-codes

Answer (score 2):

Do it with a subquery,assuming unique values on id_product

```
SELECT id_product,date  FROM products 
WHERE id_product IN
(SELECT MAX(id_product) as maxid FROM products WHERE    
fk_stat = '1' and id_order = '77185')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using `MAX(date)` from `products` and make a `JOIN` on the same table to bring the `MAX(id_product)`:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(p2.id_product) as id_product,
    MAX(p.date) as date 
FROM test.products as p
JOIN test.products AS p2 ON (p2.fk_stat=p.fk_stat AND p2.id_order=p.id_order)
WHERE p.fk_stat = '1' and p.id_order = '77185';
```

**Test:**

```
mysql> SELECT * from test.products;
+------------+---------------------+---------+----------+
| id_product | date                | fk_stat | id_order |
+------------+---------------------+---------+----------+
|          1 | 2015-06-10 00:00:00 |       2 |    77184 |
|          2 | 2015-07-20 00:00:00 |       1 |    77185 |
|          3 | 2015-07-20 00:00:00 |       1 |    77185 |
|          4 | 2015-07-20 00:00:00 |       1 |    77185 |
+------------+---------------------+---------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT MAX(p2.id_product) as id_product,MAX(p.date) as date FROM test.products as p JOIN test.products AS p2 ON (p2.fk_stat=p.fk_stat AND p2.id_order=p.id_order) WHERE p.fk_stat = '1' and p.id_order = '77185';
+------------+---------------------+
| id_product | date                |
+------------+---------------------+
|          4 | 2015-07-20 00:00:00 |
+------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: no it returns the last date "09/07/2015" but not for max id_product

Comment: Can you add some `inserts` test values?

Comment: mixing normal and aggregated fields like this is bad and won't do what you want

Comment: @oNare i added a insert values.

Comment: @Sarah try the last query, I edited it.